# What can be the reasons behind onAppWidgetOptionsChanged not getting ever called on Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to be able to hide/show items in remoteviews according to the new size of the widget.

I have put the following code in my WidgetProvider class but it never gets called. Moving the widget calls onReceive. That's all..

```
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, android.os.Bundle newOptions) {
    Log.d("WidgetProvider","onAppWidgetOptionsChanged");
    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);

};
```

What can be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you call super.onRecieve in your onRecieve method.

Answer (score 1):

Some TouchWiz devices use a broadcast to handle this instead. See my answer here: [How to catch widget size changes on devices where onAppWidgetOptionsChanged not getting called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396045/how-to-catch-widget-size-changes-on-devices-where-onappwidgetoptionschanged-not).

Hopefully that's the problem your having. Without more information though I have no idea why else you wouldn't be getting this.

Answer (score 0):

onAppWidgetOptionsChanged() callback is supported from API level 16 (4.1 +) onwards. You will get more details from the below link.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(android.content.Context, android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager, int, android.os.Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(android.content.Context,%20android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle))