# How to catch widget size changes on devices where onAppWidgetOptionsChanged not getting called?

Tags: android, android-widget

Devices like Samsung Galaxy S3 working with Android version 4.1.2 has a bug which prevents onAppWidgetOptionsChanged to be called.

So, how can we get information related to changed sizes?

Answer (score 10):

I am adding to Frankish's answer with how I handle receiving this broadcast:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Handle TouchWiz
    if(intent.getAction().contentEquals("com.sec.android.widgetapp.APPWIDGET_RESIZE")) {
        handleTouchWiz(context, intent);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

private void handleTouchWiz(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

    int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra("widgetId", 0);
    int widgetSpanX = intent.getIntExtra("widgetspanx", 0);
    int widgetSpanY = intent.getIntExtra("widgetspany", 0);

    if(appWidgetId > 0 && widgetSpanX > 0 && widgetSpanY > 0) {
        Bundle newOptions = new Bundle();
        // We have to convert these numbers for future use
        newOptions.putInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT, widgetSpanY * 74);
        newOptions.putInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH, widgetSpanX * 74);

        onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
    }
}
```

You may need to change how you handle that bundle if you are using MAX_HEIGHT or MAX_WIDTH which I am not.

Comment: since you are the one handling the action, shouldn't you avoid calling the "super.onReceive" in this case?

Comment: Anyone know if this is still relevant?  Which API level is it relevant up to?

Answer (score 4):

I have discovered that you can catch RESIZE action in onReceive function.

```
if(intent.getAction().contentEquals("com.sec.android.widgetapp.APPWIDGET_RESIZE"))
```

You'll get the following values from this intent's getExtras() bundle:

```
int appWidgetId = bundle.getInt("widgetId"); // bundle.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);


int widgetSpanX = bundle.getInt("widgetspanx", 4);
int widgetSpanY = bundle.getInt("widgetspany", 1);
```

Now you can use these values to update the view or store them in a static integer map variable to use in the next onUpdate.

Comment: "or store them in a static integer map variable" -- this will not be reliable, as your process can be terminated in between the `com.sec.android.widgetapp.APPWIDGET_RESIZE` broadcast and any subsequent `onUpdate()` call. Now, it may work out that Samsung's modified code will trigger an `onUpdate()` very shortly after `com.sec.android.widgetapp.APPWIDGET_RESIZE`, in which case static data members may work in practice.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, you may be right. It doesn't trigger onUpdate automatically, so I broadcast an update if the new size is not the same one that I have stored in the static variable. For the static variable: App is automatically started to call onReceive, so it will always set that static variable. If it gets killed at that point, it is probably caused by a crash and it shouldn't crash anyways.. otherwise we may not update the widget. Am i missing something? :| By the way, we can always make a direct update from onreceive function, if we don't care wheter the size is same or not.